# Insert Today's Date in Google Sheets on Norwegian Keyboard

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> should be the US way to insert today's date, but this doesn't work on my Norwegian keyboard.

Is there somewhere I can look up what it should be?

Answer (score 1):

**This is the combination on Norwegian keyboard:**

[image]

**If your layout is like this, then:**

[image]

Comment: Sorry , that doesn't work for me, C-Ø

Comment: I'm also on Ubuntu GNU/Linux 18.10

Comment: @JasonHunter answer updated